# how to get the tag list in wordpress mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress, tags

i want to get the following information from wordpress database relate to Tag

```
TagID TagName TagPostCount
```

Are anyone tell me and write a mysql command that give me list of this three detailed.

please don't show me PHP code. i am not really want to know about them and off-course i am relate to PHP.

how i can write a Mysql command who give me these three detailed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a MYSQL query against a wordpress db with "wp_" table prefix (the default)

```
SELECT wp_terms.`term_id` AS TagID, wp_terms.`name` AS TagName, SUM( tax.`count` ) AS TagPostCount
FROM `wp_terms`
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tax ON tax.term_id = wp_terms.term_id
GROUP BY wp_terms.`term_id`
```